# Creating a balanced dipole from two monopole chip antennas for use on small PCBs

Tags: rf, antenna, layout

I'm trying to use a monopole chip antenna on a PCB much smaller than the one recommended in the datasheet. I am wondering if I can get away with a much smaller board by using two monopole antennas driven in a balanced dipole configuration as depicted below.

**Is there any benefit to using chip antennas in this way or am I better off just using a single antenna and trying to tune it for the smaller board somehow?**

This is the antenna in question: [Yageo 433MHz chip antenna](http://www.yageo.com/documents/recent/An_SMD_UHF_433_1204_0.pdf)

Instead of the layout in the datasheet
[image: recommended PCB layout]

I was thinking of using something more like this
[image: balanced chip antennas]

Comment: Where in the data sheet does it tell you what the board dimensions must be as a minimum? Please link directly to the data sheet rather than a digikey page.

Comment: @Andyaka It doesn't, the datasheet has very little to say on such matters, it only has the evaluation board (the first image above) and the radiation patters and return loss plot for the reference design. However, I have seen notes in the datasheets for other monopole chip antennas that talk about de-tuning and reduced radiation efficiency of the parts when used with ground planes smaller than those of their 'reference designs'. If I had access to a decent vector network analyser I'd just test it but I would have to buy one first and if I'm going to buy one I'd rather get a good one.

Comment: Sounds like that needs to be addressed first then worry about duplicatingthem to a dipole.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, and if I had the tools to do that I would have, unfortunately I don't and the balanced dipole configuration seemed like a simple way to sidestep the issue